# Проверяют ли математику при собеседовании на Java джуна?

Tags: java, задание-на-собеседовании

Я не имею ввиду задачи на логические мышление.
Могут ли дать примеры различные порешать или т.п.
Было ли у вас подобное в опыте, если да, то какие темы)
Я был бы очень рад, потому что не знаю, стоит ли попрактиковаться еще и в математике.

Я понимаю, что вопрос кажется для вам смешным, но я немного нервничаю перед собеседованием)
Я был бы крайне благодарен Вам за ответ.

Comment: математика математике разница. Если Вы собеседуетесь на работу в банке (типичное для java программиста), то явно нужно уметь складывать числа и хотя бы какие то простые проценты считать ( то есть, вопрос 20 процентов от 10 не должно вызывать вопросов). А вот нужно ли вспоминать дифуры - вот тут маловерятно, нужно смотеть на целевую компанию

Comment: Если вы собеседуетесь на позицию формошлепа, то без разницы что вы умеете в математике. Если вы идете в компанию типа гугла, то математика или комбинаторика могут вам пригодиться.

Comment: и формошлеперу нужна математика. Просто я бы ее назвал арифметикой.

Comment: Главное научитесь отличать java от javascript - тогда даже за мидла сможете сойти.

Comment: Алгоритмы и структуры данных, но это скорее нужно от миддла и выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А при чем тут математика и логика? Да, на логику (алгоритмы) задачи дают. Например:

- Классический fooBar, могут попросить несколько вариантов решения (минимум ветвлений, без циклов и т.п.).
- Задачи на работу с массивами (бинарный поиск, удаление неких элементов и т.д.).
- Задачки про наследование (написать иерархию классов, описывающую некие объекты и их наследование. Например геометрические фигуры).
- Могут попросить посчитать количество каждого символа в строке (через циклы или stream api).
- По коллекциям: написать свою имплементацию списка (будь то односвязанный или основанный на массиве). Написать итератор. Но это скорее не для собеседования, а для тестовых заданий до или после него.
- По многопоточности (тоже вряд-ли на самом собеседовании, скорее в тестовых заданиях). Написать два потока, которые делают что-либо по очереди.
  Вот [хорошая статься на хабре, посвященная этой тематике](https://habr.com/ru/post/440436/).

Удачи на собеседовании!